# Update query is slow

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i make these updates query faster ,i'm no sql expert

it took +6 hours to finish ,my server is amazon RDS 2 GB RAM, 2 cpu cores with , high speed aws SSD.

products table contains 123134 rows

orders table contains 15135187 rows

the more the tables get bigger the slower the more time the query need to finish

```
UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `dailyOrders` = filterd_orders;



UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `weeklyOrders` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `monthlyOrders` = filterd_orders;

UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `nintyDaysOrdres` = filterd_orders;

UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','UK','AU','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `dailyOrdersTop4` = filterd_orders;

UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','UK','AU','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `weeklyOrdersTop4` = filterd_orders;

UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','UK','AU','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `monthlyOrdersTop4` = filterd_orders;

UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','UK','AU','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `nintyDaysOrdresTop4` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.countryCode IN ('US','UK','AU','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `AllTimeTop4Orders` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','MX','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `dailyOrdersUSMCA` = filterd_orders;

UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','MX','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `weeklyOrdersUSMCA` = filterd_orders;

UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','MX','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `monthlyOrdersUSMCA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','MX','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `nintyDaysOrdresUSMCA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.countryCode IN ('US','MX','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `AllTimeOrdresUSMCA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `dailyOrdersNA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `weeklyOrdersNA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `monthlyOrdersNA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('US','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `nintyDaysOrdresNA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.countryCode IN ('US','CA') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `AllTimesOrdresNA` = filterd_orders;



UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'US' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `dailyOrdersUS` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'US' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `weeklyOrdersUS` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'US' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `monthlyOrdersUS` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'US' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `nintyDaysOrdresUS` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.countryCode = 'US' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `AllTimeOrdresUS` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'UK' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `dailyOrdersUK` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'UK' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `weeklyOrdersUK` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'UK' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `monthlyOrdersUK` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'UK' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `nintyDaysOrdresUK` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.countryCode = 'UK' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `AllTimeOrdresUK` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'CA' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `dailyOrdersCA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'CA' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `weeklyOrdersCA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'CA' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `monthlyOrdersCA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'CA' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `nintyDaysOrdresCA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.countryCode = 'CA' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `AllTimeOrdresCA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'AU' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `dailyOrdersAU` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'AU' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `weeklyOrdersAU` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'AU' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `monthlyOrdersAU` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND t4.countryCode = 'AU' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `nintyDaysOrdresAU` = filterd_orders;




UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.countryCode = 'AU' GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `AllTimeOrdresAU` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('AT','BE','BG','HR','CY','CZ','DK','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','HU','HU','IS','IE','IT','LV','LI','LT','LU','MT','N','NO','PL','PT','RO','SK','SI','ES','SE') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `dailyOrdersEEA` = filterd_orders;



UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('AT','BE','BG','HR','CY','CZ','DK','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','HU','HU','IS','IE','IT','LV','LI','LT','LU','MT','N','NO','PL','PT','RO','SK','SI','ES','SE') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `weeklyOrdersEEA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('AT','BE','BG','HR','CY','CZ','DK','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','HU','HU','IS','IE','IT','LV','LI','LT','LU','MT','N','NO','PL','PT','RO','SK','SI','ES','SE') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `monthlyOrdersEEA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('AT','BE','BG','HR','CY','CZ','DK','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','HU','HU','IS','IE','IT','LV','LI','LT','LU','MT','N','NO','PL','PT','RO','SK','SI','ES','SE') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `nintyDaysOrdresEEA` = filterd_orders;

UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.countryCode IN ('AT','BE','BG','HR','CY','CZ','DK','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','HU','HU','IS','IE','IT','LV','LI','LT','LU','MT','N','NO','PL','PT','RO','SK','SI','ES','SE') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `AllTimeOrdresEEA` = filterd_orders;



UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('AT','BE','CY','DK','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','HU','HU','IS','IE','IT','LV','LI','LT','LU','MT','N','NO','PT','SK','SI','ES') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `dailyOrdersEA` = filterd_orders;



UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('AT','BE','CY','DK','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','HU','HU','IS','IE','IT','LV','LI','LT','LU','MT','N','NO','PT','SK','SI','ES') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `weeklyOrdersEA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('AT','BE','CY','DK','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','HU','HU','IS','IE','IT','LV','LI','LT','LU','MT','N','NO','PT','SK','SI','ES') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `monthlyOrdersEA` = filterd_orders;

UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('AT','BE','CY','DK','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','HU','HU','IS','IE','IT','LV','LI','LT','LU','MT','N','NO','PT','SK','SI','ES') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `nintyDaysOrdresEA` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.countryCode IN ('AT','BE','CY','DK','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','HU','HU','IS','IE','IT','LV','LI','LT','LU','MT','N','NO','PT','SK','SI','ES') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `AllTimeOrdresEA` = filterd_orders;



UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('BE','BG','CZ','DK','DE','EE','IE','EL','ES','FR','HR','IT','CY','LV','LT','LU','HU','MT','NL','AT','PL','PT','RO','SI','SK','FI','SE','UK') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `dailyOrdersEU` = filterd_orders;


UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('BE','BG','CZ','DK','DE','EE','IE','EL','ES','FR','HR','IT','CY','LV','LT','LU','HU','MT','NL','AT','PL','PT','RO','SI','SK','FI','SE','UK') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `weeklyOrdersEU` = filterd_orders;




UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('BE','BG','CZ','DK','DE','EE','IE','EL','ES','FR','HR','IT','CY','LV','LT','LU','HU','MT','NL','AT','PL','PT','RO','SI','SK','FI','SE','UK') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `monthlyOrdersEU` = filterd_orders;



UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND t4.countryCode IN ('BE','BG','CZ','DK','DE','EE','IE','EL','ES','FR','HR','IT','CY','LV','LT','LU','HU','MT','NL','AT','PL','PT','RO','SI','SK','FI','SE','UK') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `nintyDaysOrdresEU` = filterd_orders;



UPDATE `products` p
INNER JOIN
(select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE t4.countryCode IN ('BE','BG','CZ','DK','DE','EE','IE','EL','ES','FR','HR','IT','CY','LV','LT','LU','HU','MT','NL','AT','PL','PT','RO','SI','SK','FI','SE','UK') GROUP by productId) o
ON p.productID = o.productId
SET `AllTimeOrdresEU` = filterd_orders;
```

Products Table

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `productId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `detailUrl` text CHARACTER SET utf32 NOT NULL,
 `belongToDSStore` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `promPCPriceStr` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
 `oriPriceStr` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
 `orderCnt` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `productTitle` text CHARACTER SET utf32 NOT NULL,
 `productImgUrl` text CHARACTER SET utf32 NOT NULL,
 `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `cat` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
 `dailyOrders` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `weeklyOrders` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `monthlyOrders` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nintyDaysOrdres` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dailyOrdersTop4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `weeklyOrdersTop4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `monthlyOrdersTop4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nintyDaysOrdresTop4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `AllTimeTop4Orders` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dailyOrdersEEA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `weeklyOrdersEEA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `monthlyOrdersEEA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nintyDaysOrdresEEA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `AllTimeOrdresEEA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dailyOrdersUSMCA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `weeklyOrdersUSMCA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `monthlyOrdersUSMCA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nintyDaysOrdresUSMCA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `AllTimeOrdresUSMCA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dailyOrdersEA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `weeklyOrdersEA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `monthlyOrdersEA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nintyDaysOrdresEA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `AllTimeOrdresEA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dailyOrdersEU` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `weeklyOrdersEU` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `monthlyOrdersEU` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nintyDaysOrdresEU` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `AllTimeOrdresEU` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dailyOrdersNA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `weeklyOrdersNA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `monthlyOrdersNA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nintyDaysOrdresNA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `AllTimesOrdresNA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dailyOrdersUS` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `weeklyOrdersUS` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `monthlyOrdersUS` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nintyDaysOrdresUS` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `AllTimeOrdresUS` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dailyOrdersUK` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `weeklyOrdersUK` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `monthlyOrdersUK` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nintyDaysOrdresUK` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `AllTimeOrdresUK` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `dailyOrdersCA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `weeklyOrdersCA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `monthlyOrdersCA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nintyDaysOrdresCA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `AllTimeOrdresCA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dailyOrdersAU` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `weeklyOrdersAU` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `monthlyOrdersAU` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nintyDaysOrdresAU` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `AllTimeOrdresAU` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `isEditorPick` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `productId` (`productId`),
 KEY `orderCnt` (`orderCnt`),
 KEY `cat` (`cat`),
 KEY `promPCPriceStr` (`promPCPriceStr`),
 KEY `dailyOrders` (`dailyOrders`),
 KEY `weeklyOrders` (`weeklyOrders`),
 KEY `monthlyOrders` (`monthlyOrders`),
 KEY `nintyDaysOrdres` (`nintyDaysOrdres`),
 KEY `dailyOrdersTop4` (`dailyOrdersTop4`),
 KEY `weeklyOrdersTop4` (`weeklyOrdersTop4`),
 KEY `monthlyOrdersTop4` (`monthlyOrdersTop4`),
 KEY `nintyDaysOrdresTop4` (`nintyDaysOrdresTop4`),
 KEY `dailyOrdersEEA` (`dailyOrdersEEA`),
 KEY `weeklyOrdersEEA` (`weeklyOrdersEEA`),
 KEY `monthlyOrdersEEA` (`monthlyOrdersEEA`),
 KEY `nintyDaysOrdresEEA` (`nintyDaysOrdresEEA`),
 KEY `dailyOrdersUSMCA` (`dailyOrdersUSMCA`),
 KEY `weeklyOrdersUSMCA` (`weeklyOrdersUSMCA`),
 KEY `monthlyOrdersUSMCA` (`monthlyOrdersUSMCA`),
 KEY `nintyDaysOrdresUSMCA` (`nintyDaysOrdresUSMCA`),
 KEY `dailyOrdersEA` (`dailyOrdersEA`),
 KEY `weeklyOrdersEA` (`weeklyOrdersEA`),
 KEY `monthlyOrdersEA` (`monthlyOrdersEA`),
 KEY `nintyDaysOrdresEA` (`nintyDaysOrdresEA`),
 KEY `dailyOrdersEU` (`dailyOrdersEU`),
 KEY `weeklyOrdersEU` (`weeklyOrdersEU`),
 KEY `monthlyOrdersEU` (`monthlyOrdersEU`),
 KEY `nintyDaysOrdresEU` (`nintyDaysOrdresEU`),
 KEY `dailyOrdersNA` (`dailyOrdersNA`),
 KEY `weeklyOrdersNA` (`weeklyOrdersNA`),
 KEY `monthlyOrdersNA` (`monthlyOrdersNA`),
 KEY `nintyDaysOrdresNA` (`nintyDaysOrdresNA`),
 KEY `dailyOrdersUS` (`dailyOrdersUS`),
 KEY `weeklyOrdersUS` (`weeklyOrdersUS`),
 KEY `monthlyOrdersUS` (`monthlyOrdersUS`),
 KEY `nintyDaysOrdresUS` (`nintyDaysOrdresUS`),
 KEY `dailyOrdersUK` (`dailyOrdersUK`),
 KEY `weeklyOrdersUK` (`weeklyOrdersUK`),
 KEY `monthlyOrdersUK` (`monthlyOrdersUK`),
 KEY `nintyDaysOrdresUK` (`nintyDaysOrdresUK`),
 KEY `dailyOrdersCA` (`dailyOrdersCA`),
 KEY `weeklyOrdersCA` (`weeklyOrdersCA`),
 KEY `monthlyOrdersCA` (`monthlyOrdersCA`),
 KEY `nintyDaysOrdresCA` (`nintyDaysOrdresCA`),
 KEY `dailyOrdersAU` (`dailyOrdersAU`),
 KEY `weeklyOrdersAU` (`weeklyOrdersAU`),
 KEY `monthlyOrdersAU` (`monthlyOrdersAU`),
 KEY `nintyDaysOrdresAU` (`nintyDaysOrdresAU`),
 KEY `AllTimeTop4Orders` (`AllTimeTop4Orders`),
 KEY `AllTimeOrdresUSMCA` (`AllTimeOrdresUSMCA`),
 KEY `AllTimeOrdersNA` (`AllTimesOrdresNA`),
 KEY `AllTimeOrdresUS` (`AllTimeOrdresUS`),
 KEY `AllTimeOrdresUK` (`AllTimeOrdresUK`),
 KEY `AllTimeOrdresCA` (`AllTimeOrdresCA`),
 KEY `AllTimeOrdresAU` (`AllTimeOrdresAU`),
 KEY `AllTimeOrdresEEA` (`AllTimeOrdresEEA`),
 KEY `AllTimeOrdresEA` (`AllTimeOrdresEA`),
 KEY `AllTimeOrdresEU` (`AllTimeOrdresEU`),
 KEY `isEditorPick` (`isEditorPick`),
 KEY `created_date` (`created_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=247877 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Orders table

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
 `oid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `countryCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `productId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`oid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `date` (`date`),
 KEY `productId` (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101646228 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to create a temporary table that will have productid and all those order total columns (dailyOrdersAU, weeklyOrdersAU, etc.) then you just run one update for the "product" table. You can create index on temp table as well. The main problem with your queries is that using subquery basically negates your index on productID. Here is a tutorial to temporary tables:http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/

Comment: can you explain more what you mean , i don't get the temp table part.

Comment: you are running a bunch of queries to get daily, weekly, monthly totals, etc. You can store the results of these queries in a temporary table. After that you just run one update to change totals in the product table.

Comment: will im testing this it seems promising i will get back to you.